# xCode Isntrument vs real device for producing crash?

Tags: xcode, device, instruments

I want to know that testing in real device and the instrument is same? only for producing crash. that means the crash which produced in device will be produced in instruments also?

Note: ARC enabled projects

Comment: When you say "instruments", do you mean "iphone simulator"?

Comment: yes but launched from instruments...

Comment: why aren't you running instruments again the real device?

Comment: @marko To check the memory leaks and the amount of living bytes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% crashes happenning on devices will also happen on simulators (ie can be instrumented), that is, as long as you have covered all possible combinations of iOS version and device type - iPhone / iPad, and with exception of features not supported by simulators: phone call, location tracking, motions etc.

Testing on devices however is strongly recommended, not because of 1% crashes, but because the experience of user with a device is very different from that with a simulator. Examples: a tiny button can easily be clicked with a mouse / trackpad, but might not be accessible with a finger; element sizes / colors might feel different on a real device...